# What is the appropriate ratio of medics?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic

What is the appropriate ratio of Medics to team size for most non-pro games?  I'm fairly sure one medic in twelve players isn't effective.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A straight ratio isn't the best, because there are some classes that the medic doesn't synergize well with (engineer, spy). A better metric would be 1 medic for every 4-5 offensive classes, so 2-3 medics on a 12 person team.

Comment: I would agree with this. You can definitely get away with 1 medic if they are very good at not dying. It's also highly dependant on what game mode your playing.

Comment: If you only have 1 medic, your team runs the risk of him being targetted by enemy spies (and then rage quitting). At least, that's what I would be doing if I were an enemy spy and saw that the other team had only 1 medic.

Answer (score 13):

There's not a set ratio, but they key is to at least have 2 because medics are exponentially better when they can heal each other. 1 medic is bad not because they can't heal as many targets (though of course that's bad), but because when they get hurt, they have to back off the line to heal themselves.

Comment: Unless you have a good heavy who knows to toss his Sandvich when his medic gets hurt.

Comment: Medics also regain health over time, so the medic generally doesn't need to run back and heal unless he is on fire or at such low health that a stray bullet would kill him.

Answer (score 10):

I'll add one more answer: it depends on what stage of the game you're in and what mode you're playing. In Attack/Defense, if you're on BLU, it's very helpful to have more medics than usual at the beginning of the round (as long as each of them has an offensive player to buddy up with) because they can all build up an Ubercharge before the round starts. Then when the gates open they can Ubercharge more than one offensive class player at the beginning, or extend an Uber started by another Medic on a Heavy or Pyro (which is what I usually do, RED is usually ready for Ubers out of the gate with their own Uber but they don't expect yours to last twice as long). I'll often start a round as a medic and then switch to another class after that first uber is spent, assuming there's another medic on my team.

In CTF, the Quick Fix is handy for buddying up with Scouts, since it speeds up the Medic to the Scout's speed and its super-healing Ubercharge doesn't prevent the Scout from grabbing the intelligence (which the normal Medi-gun uber does).

Comment: +1 for the CTF bit. That Quick Fix loophole never occurred to me.

Comment: Thanks! In practice, it's not terribly useful, since as soon as the Scout grabs the intel he's usually going to be double-jumping and triple-jumping away, which the medic can't do and in my experience it doesn't take long to get separated from the Scout. But with their puny health, every little bit helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're playing with a team of 12 people and someone else has your role, then become a medic and support him. My ratio would be 5-1 or 4-1 depending what class they are.

Answer (score 1):

It's very tough to give a hard-and-fast rule about this, since it varies by map and game type, and also depends on what classes / tactics the enemy team is using, as well as what classes your teammates are already playing.  It also depends on how many medics the other team has.

*Generally speaking* the team with more medics will win, as long as there are ample "offensive class" players to heal. Generally Heavy, Soldier, Demoman, and Pyro are the classes that pair well with medics.

If you have one medic on a 12 player team, and the other team has zero, you'll probably win faster if you go for one of the powerful attacking classes than if you decided to switch two players to medic.

For example, if the enemy team has decided to turtle with a lot of sentries, and your team is full of scouts, snipers, engineers, and spies, you probably will help out a lot more by switching to Demoman or Soldier to counter the sentry positions than you would by trying to heal those other classes as a medic.

Comment: Not sure about this. Having a second medic will double the chances for ubercharging to push through the defenses.

Answer (score 0):

I usually switch to medic if one heavy is present and no medic support him. I would say 1 medic foe 2 heavys.

On the other hand, like Raven Dreamer said, 1 medic for 4-5 offensive players is nice.

Answer (score 0):

At least 1 per every 5 players, with 3 of them being offensive is usually what we roll with.